# SOQL For loop doesn't run in 200 size batch

Tags: apex, soql, limits

Executing this block runs the first batch with a size of 200. But, the next batch returns the rest of the records.

```
Integer i = 1;
for(Account acc : [SELECT Id FROM Account]){
     system.debug('rows '+Limits.getQueryRows()+ 'row number = '+(i++));
}
```

Say you have 5000 accounts in your org. the Limits.getQueryRows() will print 200 for the first 200 records. The 201st row will have 4800 returned for Limits.getQueryRows().

Comment: This isn't a "SOQL for loop", it's a for loop iterating over individual records returned from a SOQL query. A SOQL for loop iterates over arrays of records, like `for ( Account[] accs : [select Id from Account] ) {`. This should give you the results you're looking for.

Comment: @JCD, this still returns `queryLocator` and `queryMore` is invoked for every record. Question is valid - why initially 200 but later 5000.

Comment: @sandeep... correction - it returns 5000 from 201st record and not 4800

Comment: @salesforce-sas, yes you're correct. What I meant was it returned the rest 4800 records for the next batch.

Comment: @JCD, This in fact is a SOQL for loop. The difference being the first will iterate over the single record and the one you mentioned will iterate over a list. My question is, why the record returned for the initial batch is 200 and the rest of the records are returned for the next batch! (for the code which i have written)

Comment: The documentation mentions that "SOQL for loops retrieve all sObjects, using efficient chunking with calls to the query and queryMore methods of the SOAP API." It does not state how many records each chunk of queryMore will return. When you use a single variable, SF will return one record at a time (irrespective of how it is using queryMore in the background), when you use a list, SF will ensure that you receive 200 records per iteration in the list.